# Apple App store accessed programmatically

Tags: objective-c, api, app-store, xcode4.4

I would like to display in a button or a form some info from the Apple AppStore page related to the App the user is currently running.

e.g. the price in the current country or the reviews summary.

is there any function that can be called via xcode to extract those details without using additional external libraries?

I am referring to Apps that i created , so i have all the IDs...

Thank you
A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page should contain the information you need: http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=your_app_id

Answer (score 1):

Their is a built-in iOS API for accessing the prices of in-app-purchase items.  Otherwise, you may have to research 3rd pary libraries or send the user to a Safari or App store URL for the information.